# relation between the roots of the cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If L,M and N are the roots of the equation
$$x^3 -2x^2 +3x-1=0$$
Then , find
$$1)  L+M+N$$
$$2)\frac{1}{L}+\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{N}$$
I know the relation between the roots of the cubic equation but i want to get it using this equation ?

Comment: Well, it's easy to read off the sum of the roots from the coefficients, yes?  Just multiply out $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ to see it if you aren't clear.  For the second, think about the polynomial $q(x)=x^3p\left(\frac 1x\right)$ where $p(x)$ denotes your polynomial.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So, you know that $LMN=1$, $LM+MN+NL=3$, $L+M+N=2$. (Vieta's formulas.) This answers the first question.

The second one: use the fact that $\frac{1}{L}+\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{N}=\frac{LM+MN+NL}{LMN}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$L+M+N = 2$$

$$\frac{1}{L}+\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{N}=\frac{LM+MN+NL}{LMN}=3$$

**NOTE**

to find this relations **simply expand**

$$(x-L)(x-M)(x-N)=0$$